# LibGDX fps drop by just moving one object

Tags: android, libgdx, frame-rate

I am moving a single object in libgdx but animation is not smooth. I tested on my LG device and also on genymotion but fps is less than 60. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Please tell me why fps is dropping. Here is my fps log and code

[FPS LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHOAk.png)

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

int x;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Texture texture;
Sprite sprite;
FPSLogger fpsLogger;

int screenWidth;

@Override
public void create() {

    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    texture = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    fpsLogger = new FPSLogger();
    screenWidth = 1080;
}

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    spriteBatch.begin();

    if (x > screenWidth)
        x = 0;
    x = x + 10;

    spriteBatch.draw(sprite, x, 0);
    spriteBatch.end();
    fpsLogger.log();
 }
}
```

Comment: always multiplay anything related to movement with delta time: x = x + (100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

Comment: i tried but no improvement also when i just only display object (no animation) just simply draw sprite then also similarly fps drops down.

Comment: I don't think that this app has anything common with FPS drops - it is really simple and if it only logic of your game the reason must be somewhere else

Comment: i just created project using libgdx setup jar file. what other things should i check to resolve this issue

Comment: First of all you shouldn't do game logic (like translation in the render loop) read this awesome tutorial http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/ and in second place 55fps can be normal (doesn't matter the render complexity in this case)

Comment: thanks Saret for tutorial. but fps is varying from 60 to 48 without doing translation and any other thing in render loop

Comment: I'm thinking the problem is internal to FPSlogger.

Comment: i don't think so because i can cleary see jerk on screen while animation

Comment: I'm saying that the FPSLogger is causing the slowdown, not that it's logging the wrong FPS. Can you share the code of its log() method?

Comment: public void log () {
  if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - startTime > 1000000000) /* 1,000,000,000ns == one second */{
   Gdx.app.log("FPSLogger", "fps: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());
   startTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
  }
 }